# How to get rid of a fitter warning about LVDS complement pin?

Tags: verilog, intel-fpga

I have a clock input to the fan-out buffer which drives LVDS input to the bottom edge of PLL input. There are two pins - `AJ19` (active high) and a complementary `AK19` pin (active low). I am only interested in `AJ19`, so my top level module looks like this:

```
module top(clk, ...);
...
endmodule
```

Here is my pinout for a `clk`:

```
set_instance_assignment -name IO_STANDARD LVDS -to clk
set_location_assignment PIN_AJ19 -to clk
set_location_assignment PIN_AK19 -to "clk(n)"
```

So far so good, but fitter is generating a very annoying warning that drives me crazy:

```
Warning (15714): Some pins have incomplete I/O assignments. Refer to the I/O Assignment Warnings report for details
Warning (176674): Following 1 pins are differential I/O pins but do not have their complement pins. Hence, the Fitter automatically created the complement pins.
    Warning (176118): Pin "clk" is a differential I/O pin but does not have its complement pin. Hence, fitter automatically created the complement pin "clk(n)"
```

Altera's knowledge base suggested to actually define the clock as a pair (i.e. `input wire [1:0] clk`) to remove the warning. That doesn't quite help because then you get another warning, saying that input pin does not drive any logic.

I have tried to disable this warning using `// altera message_off 176118`. That results in error because "176118" is not a valid message ID.

Any suggestions on how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See Altera "Designing with Low-Level Primitives User Guide" for primitive details and templates
http://www.altera.co.uk/literature/ug/ug_low_level.pdf

Example of wrapping top level block:

```
module top_wrap (
    ...
    input wire refclk,  input wire refclk_n,
  );

    // differential input buffers
  wire int_refclk;
  ALT_INBUF_DIFF inbuf_refclk (
    .i (refclk),
    .ibar (refclk_n),
    .o(int_refclk),
  );

  top wrapped (
      .refclk( int_refclk),
      ...
  )
endmodule
```

Answer (score 2):

To get rid of this, you need to create both signals, and then take them into an LVDS buffer component (I don't recall what Altera calls this component off the top of my head), the output of which will drive a "normal" internal signal that you can then use as you see fit.

Comment: `ALTIOBUF` can do the job. Some devices also support `ALT_INBUF_DIF`. But the thing is that I don't really need those from functional point of view. So I guess I will have to live with this silly warning.

Comment: @VladLazarenko: You do need them functionally, in that you want to use differential IOs - even though you are only interested in the output of the buffer, IMHO putting the buffer in is the right thing.  I often create a wrapper around my highest level "functional "HDL file to do this sort of distracting stuff

Comment: Hm... maybe you are right. The strange thing is that in every reference design from Altera the second half of the LVDS clock is not used for some reason.